How to add feedback system for a CNC machine which drived by stepper motor?
I have an old CNC machine to retrofit. In this machines stepper motors without are used and those motor are not double shaft, so how can I make a feedback for this system if it is possible?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

"stepper motors without are used" motors without what?

(Stepper motors often were used with limit switches, the assumption being no step dropped.)

Perhaps you mean external stepper motors?

If you had a photo or diagram of the machine that would really help: a lot depends on your physical constraints.  Basically what it comes down to is where can you put a sensor.

One way to do it is to use a "yo-yo" or draw-wire encoder.

Figure 1. Image source: Dynapar.
These do not attach to the motor directly, but rather to somewhere else on the machine to monitor the actual position of the mechanism being driven. In operation they are rather like a tape measure in that they retract automatically by spring.
Adding an encoder to a stepper-driven system requires a more complex stepper driver unit that can make use of the position data.

Try and make the mechanical measurement loop independent from the force loop. Think 4 lead resistance measurement via a current forcing connection and a sensing voltage connection.
